# Como usar o Atlassian Connect para obter dados do Jira e gerar um JSON?

Tags: json, api

Preciso fazer um script que obtenha alguns dados do [Jira](https://br.atlassian.com/software/jira) 
e acredito que para isso tenha que usar a API [Atlassian Connect](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/integrating-with-jira-cloud/) que utiliza um servidor em Node.js.

Entretanto, eu não quero manipular os dados utilizando a API e sim apenas obter eles e manipular com outra linguagem.

Então é possível  utilizar apenas a API e gerar um arquivo JSON com os dados obtidos? Como?

Comment: No próprio [site](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis) possui tutoriais de como usar a api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Atlassian Connect permite criar extensões (integrações ou plugins, dependendo de como você prefira chamar) e não é necessário se você apenas quer fazer algumas requisições para os *endpoints* do Jira.

Conforme já apontado em comentários, existe uma [farta documentação](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis) na seção de desenvolvedores.

A primeira coisa a se atentar é qual o tipo de serviço com o qual está lidando, isto é: *Cloud* (hospedado pela Atlassian) ou *Server* (instalado na sua empresa).

Dependendo do que você quer, a diferença entre tais versões vai ser apenas o método de autenticação, mas geralmente você pode usar [autenticação HTTP básica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), só precisa ter ou buscar obter as credenciais necessárias.

---

Por exemplo, se você quiser consultar pendências (*issues*) de um projeto, existe  uma API que permite executar [qualquer *query* JQL via REST](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/?_ga=2.184873769.1052386625.1505092103-1410749275.1496944369#api/2/search) e pegar o resultado em JSON. Use qualquer linguagem para isso.

No caso do site jira.spring.io, testei o seguinte comando para pesquisar todos os bugs to projeto `spr`:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data \
    '{ "jql": "project = spr AND issuetype = \"bug\"","startAt": 0,"maxResults": 15,"fields": ["summary","status","issuetype"]}' \
    https://jira.spring.io/rest/api/2/search
```

O legal é que funciona de forma anônima, sem precisar de credenciais, por se tratar de um projeto público.

Você pode personalizar a busca para suas necessidades e também pesquisar outros *endpoints* se precisar de outras informações.

Comment: Preciso  fazer um script que obtenha algumas informações  dessa pagina do spring framework  https://jira.spring.io/browse/spr/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel como bugs e algumas outras coisas para uma pesquisa, apenas me informaram de uma possível api para isso. caso exista uma forma mais simples de obter os dados para meu script ficaria grato em saber

Comment: @Arcashaid Veja a resposta  atualizada acima

Comment: So não entendi direito qual api esta falando, o link leva para o meio de uma pagina da atlassian com muitos outros links, qual o nome da api ?

Comment: @Arcashaid A API que me refiro é o conjunto de endpoints que você pode acessar. Esta é a API do Jira. Se você quer uma biblioteca cliente ou command line interface que forneça uma API cliente para acessar a API do servidor, aí é outra história. Bibliotecas existem, mas exige que você faça algum programa. Ferramentas de linha de comando eu desconheço. REST endpoints são muito fáceis de trabalhar em qualquer linguagem.

Comment: A escolha de linguagem depende do background de cada um, mas devido a facilidade de manipulação de JSON em JavaScript, se você não tem nada pronto em outra linguagem, eu aconselharia você instalar o Node e implementar uma ferramenta de linha de comando (não precisa de servidor) em JavaScript para fazer a interação com o JIRA. Mas, como disse, pode ser em qualquer linguagem.